# There's an Indexerror when I use drop() function in module 'Pandas'

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N15jj.png)

The code below is what I have coded:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, np.nan, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
              columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])


for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i,:].notna().to_list().count(False)>=1:
        df.drop([i],inplace=True)
```

The error is following:
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: The code is dropping rows from the dataframe, which changes its length. Meanwhile the loop iterates over the range corresponding to the original length of the dataframe, so the iteration goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem with your current code

Here's what happens when your loop is iterated.

### Before running the loop

**`df` is:**

```
    A     B   C
0   0   NaN   3
1   0   4.0   1
2  10  20.0  30
```

The first line of the loop is `for i in range(len(df)`. `len(df)` is 3, so `range(len(df)` is `[0, 1, 2]` and the code inside the loop will execute for each of these three values of `i`.

### i = 0

`df.iloc[0,:]` is:

```
0   NaN   3
```

This contains an `na` value, so it is dropped.

**`df` is now:**

```
    A     B   C
1   0   4.0   1
2  10  20.0  30
```

### i = 1

`df.iloc[1,:]` is:

```
10  20.0  30
```

This row does not contain an `na` value, so it is not dropped. **Note that the row containing 0, 4.0, 1 was never checked.**

**`df` is still:**

```
    A     B   C
1   0   4.0   1
2  10  20.0  30
```

### i = 2

`df` only has two rows, `0` and `1`, so `df.iloc[2,:]` does not exist. This is where the `IndexError` occurs.

The above behaviour is why you should never remove elements of an object while you are iterating over it. This applies to lists as well as pandas dataframes. In general, it is not usually a good idea to iterate over pandas dataframes as they come with a wide range of methods for doing almost anything you could ever need to do in a more stable and efficient manner.

## What you should do instead

[pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```